# Presenting the solution of an equation with the form of x=

Tags: equation-solving, output-formatting

In Maple you can use `{}` inside the command in order to present the evaluation as x=... For instance, the command `solve({x^2+2x+1=0}, {x})` generates {x=-1},{x=-1}.

So, I wonder if there is a way to say to Mathematica that I want to present the solution of an equation as x=...

Comment: Use `Reduce`, e.g., `Reduce[x^2 + 2 x + 1 == 0, x]` evaluates to `x == -1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
HoldForm[Evaluate[Solve[x^2 + 2 x + 1 == 0]]] /. Rule -> Set
```

Comment: could you please give me an example?

Comment: @Yorgos I don't understand what you are asking. Have you tried evaluating John's expression? It does exactly what you ask.

Comment: Since I use Maple much more than Mathematica I used "enter" for evaluation, forgetting that in Mathematica you have to use "shift+enter" :P

Comment: Or use `... /. Rule -> Equal` if you prefer Wolframese.

Comment: Yes, @Michael. If you do that, you don't need the evaluation control, so the expression becomes `Solve[x^2 + 2 x + 1 == 0] /. Rule -> Equal`.